# One point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, spheres

I'd like to understand the first proof given to me of the fact that the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n}$.

The proof goes as follows : there is an initial remark  about $i: \mathbb{R}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^{n}$ being an open embedding (with the identification of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as $\mathbb{S}^{n}-\left\lbrace x_{0}\right\rbrace$) and then it states that we only have to proof that the euclidean topology of $\mathbb{S}^{n}$ coincides with the Alexandrov topology on the compactification of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

I don't understand how checking the open subset's conditions is sufficient to deduces the homomorphism. Are we using some uniqueness of the Alexandrov topology ?

However I know there is a much simpler way, which is to proof in general that if a topological space $X$ is compact and Hausdorff then it is homeomorphic to the one point compactification of $X$ minus a point, but I'm interested in understanding this one.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t understand your question: if the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb S^n$ coincides with the topology of the one-point compactification of $\Bbb R^n$ when $x_0$ is taken as the point at infinity, then by definition $\Bbb S^n$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $\Bbb R^n$. What is the problem?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't see the homeomorphism given "by definition", is $\phi$ Seng described ?

Comment: You don’t need an actual homeomorphism if you’ve proved that the topologies are the same. (Though doing that does implicitly construct a homeomorphism that is $i$ on $\Bbb R^n$ and sends $\infty$ to $x_0$.)

Comment: Okay thanks, got the point.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $a\in K$, $K'=K\setminus\{a\}$
and $K'^+=K'\cup\{\infty\}$ be the one-point compactification of $K'$. Then $\phi:K'^+\to K$ given by inclusion on $K'$ and $\phi(\infty)=a$ is a homeomorphism.

One just has to prove that $\phi$ is continuous, since then $\phi$ is a continuous
bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, it must be a homeomorphism.

Continuity of $\phi$ at all points of $K'$ is obvious. What about continuity at $\infty$?
If $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $a$ in $K$ then $\phi^{-1}(U)=(U\setminus\{a\})\cup\{\infty\}$. The complement of $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is $K\setminus U$ which is a compact
subset of $K\setminus\{a\}$, so  $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is open by the definition of the
topology on the one-point compactification.

Comment: Isn’t this simply the general result that the OP mentions at the end of the question? (Also proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249610/question-regarding-one-point-compactification-and-homeomorphisms/249619#249619) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427052/showing-one-point-compactification-is-unique-up-to-homeomorphism/427131#427131).) If so, I’m not sure that it really answers the question.